# Mouseover not displaying each iteration from List [Aura]

Tags: lightning, aura

I'm trying to use the Mouse Over functionality to display info from a List for each item in a Lightning component table. The issue is when I hover over an item it is showing the info for all the files not just the highlighted one.

[image]

Component

```
<aura:attribute name="lstFiles" type="Object[]" />
<aura:attribute name="tooltip" type="boolean" default="false" />

<aura:iteration items="{!v.lstFiles}" var="objLst" indexVar="index">
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">
            <!-- <div class="slds-truncate">
                {!objLst.name}
            </div> -->
            
            <div style="position:relative">
                <a href="" aria-describedby="help" onmouseover="{!c.showToolTip}" onmouseout="{!c.HideToolTip}">{!objLst.name}</a>
                
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.tooltip}" >
                <div class="slds-popover slds-popover_tooltip slds-nubbin_left" role="tooltip" id="help" style="position:absolute;top:-4px;left:35px">
                
                <div class="slds-popover__body">Owner: {!objLst.owner} Date:{!objLst.createdDate}</div>
                </div>
                </aura:if>
                </div>
         </th>
    </tr>
```

Controller

```
showToolTip : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.tooltip" , true);
},

HideToolTip : function(component, event, helper){
    component.set("v.tooltip" , false);
}
```

Comment: You are using a single variable for all tooltips which is causing all of them to show at same time. You should add the boolean when you get the data in each recird so that each tool tip sets unsets it's own boolean. Also, it think it can also be achieved using the :hover sudo class in CSS without any JS code

Comment: Great, thank you. I'm a bit unclear how to accomplish this as I'm new to lightning/javascript and I was trying to use code I found. How would I set the boolean to know which data row is the one to display on the hover info?

Comment: @manjit5190, answers go down there, and I'd appreciate more detail as well. Thank you.